# Hide Command Prompt

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a Visual Basic Script file that is to execute a command line. The script works, but the problem is that when the the command line is executed, `cmd.exe` remains open. I would like to execute the command line without `cmd.exe` staying open. I would even be okay with it flashing for a second and then disappearing, but I do not want it to remain. How can I rewrite my program so that the command prompt can still do its thing without showing up? Here's my code for my existing program. I am using this script to schedule a backup with the development build of [Duplicati 2.0](http://www.duplicati.com/). For security reasons, I have removed the part of the command that starts the backup.

```
Dim Shell
Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Shell.Run "cmd.exe /C cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Duplicati"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all what the script does is the posted code, then

```
Dim Shell
    Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Duplicati"
```

should do the same without having to run cmd

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add ,0 to the .Run method it should hide the window 
`Shell.Run "cmd.exe /C cd C:\",0`

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)